# Android Studio. NullPointerException without any links to my project

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, jsoup

I'm using jsoup to get some data from a website and filter it then show it on ListView but I'm getting a weird error everytime no matter what I do with my code. It doesn't has any link to my project but rather has links to Android libraries and some weird things like zygote and etc.
Here is my code:

```
package com.shapedhorizon.teymur.epiknovel;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;


public class SeriInfo extends AppCompatActivity {


    ListView listView ;
    Context ncontext;
    String[] tts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_seri_info);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //something
            }
        });
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        ncontext = this;
        listView = findViewById(R.id.seri_bolum);
        Log.i("Message", message);
        AsyncInternet task = new AsyncInternet();
        task.execute(message);
        Log.i("OMG", "You got to be kidding with me");
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            }
        });
        return;
    }
    private class AsyncInternet extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
            Elements els;
            Document doc= null;
            Log.e("try",strings[0]);
            try {
                int ttsi = 0;
                doc = Jsoup.connect(strings[0]).get();
                els = doc.getElementsByAttributeValueStarting("href","https://www.epiknovel.com/seri");
                Integer size = 0;
                for (Element e: els
                        ) {
                    if(!(e==null)) {
                        if(!e.parent().tagName("span").text().contains("Premium")){

                            size++;

                            Log.i("e.text",e.text());
                        }
                    }
                }
                Log.e("size", size.toString());
                tts = new String[size];
                for (Element e: els
                        ) {

                    if(!(e==null)) {
                        if(!e.parent().tagName("span").text().contains("Premium")){
                            Log.i("e.text",e.text());
                            tts[ttsi] = e.text();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException c) {
                c.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            if(!(tts ==null)) {
                Log.i("tts","IS NOT NULL");
                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ncontext, R.layout.seri_view, tts);
                Log.i("Adapter", "Check if we set up the adapter");
                if(!(adapter==null)) {
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    Log.i("LW", "Weird that we passed that part");
                }else{
                    Log.e("ADAPTER", "IS NULL");
                }
            }else{
                Log.e("tts","IS NULL");
            }
            Log.i("OMG","Still?! What the hell is wrong with you?!");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

and my error is:l

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.shapedhorizon.teymur.epiknovel, PID: 27846
                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                      at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:401)
                      at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:369)
                      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2474)
                      at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1301)
                      at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1203)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19162)
                      at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:934)
                      at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:973)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19162)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6115)
                      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
                      at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:91)
                      at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1361)
                      at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:784)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19162)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6115)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:223)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19162)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6115)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1723)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:788)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:648)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19162)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6115)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:223)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19162)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6115)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1723)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:788)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:648)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19162)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6115)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:223)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2690)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19162)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2530)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1490)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1371)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6773)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:896)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:698)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:633)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:882)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5811)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:768)
```

**EDIT 1:** I added

```
for (Object obj: tts
                 ) {
                if (obj.equals(null)){
                    Log.e("BIG ERROR", "There is null in tts");
                }
            }
```

inside doInBackground function and I got a new error:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
                  Process: com.shapedhorizon.teymur.epiknovel, PID: 30862
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                      at com.shapedhorizon.teymur.epiknovel.SeriInfo$AsyncInternet.doInBackground(SeriInfo.java:102)
                      at com.shapedhorizon.teymur.epiknovel.SeriInfo$AsyncInternet.doInBackground(SeriInfo.java:62)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) `
```

and (SeriInfo.java:102) refers to `if (obj.equals(null)){`

**EDIT 2:** I changed array as List. Here is what has been changed in *AsyncInternet* function:

```
private class AsyncInternet extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<String>>{

    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(String... strings) {
        Elements els;
        Document doc= null;
        List<String> adapterData = new ArrayList<>();
        Log.e("try",strings[0]);
        try {
            int ttsi = 0;
            doc = Jsoup.connect(strings[0]).get();
            els = doc.getElementsByAttributeValueStarting("href","https://www.epiknovel.com/seri");
            for (Element e: els
                    ) {

                    if(!e.parent().tagName("span").text().contains("Premium")){
                        if(e.text() != null) {
                            if(e.parent().parent().html().contains("td")) {
                                Log.i("e.text", e.text());
                                adapterData.add(e.text());
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException c) {
            c.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ncontext, R.layout.seri_view, result);
        Log.i("Adapter", "set up the adapter");
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        Log.i("LW", "Weird that we passed that part");
    }
}
```

}

And now I got error like:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.shapedhorizon.teymur.epiknovel, PID: 5914
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
                  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:337)
                  at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:491)
                  at com.shapedhorizon.teymur.epiknovel.SeriInfo$AsyncInternet.onPostExecute(SeriInfo.java:97)
                  at com.shapedhorizon.teymur.epiknovel.SeriInfo$AsyncInternet.onPostExecute(SeriInfo.java:63)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

*(SeriInfo.java:97)* is `listView.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: What does ``tts`` look like? It might contain a null element.

Comment: `if(!(adapter==null)) `. Change to `if(adapter!=null)`. You have more of them.

Comment: Well quickly, it's probably because `e.text()` is null, that's why the adapter sends NullPointerException when calling toString() on the element

Comment: `obj.equals(null)` will **always** throw a nullpointerexception if true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters `== null` is a proper null check. And you can negate it with `!= null`.

But anyway, I would recommend not using an Array, and using a List for the adapter.

Start with

```
extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<String>>
```

Then

```
    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(String... strings) {
        Elements els;
        Document doc= null;
        List<String> adapterData = new ArrayList<>();
        Log.e("try",strings[0]);
        try {
            // add non null strings to adapterData 
        } catch (IOException c) {
            c.printStackTrace();
        }
        return adapterData;
 }
```

And now you have a non null list object in onPostExecute. And the adapter isn't null if you initialized it here

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ncontext, R.layout.seri_view, result);
            Log.i("Adapter", "set up the adapter");
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            Log.i("LW", "Weird that we passed that part");
    }
```

You should also, really move the adapter to a field in the Activity, and initialize it with an empty list in onCreate

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

I got this

Comment: It cannot be null if you create the Arraylist before the try and return after the catch.... Look closely at your code. You have a `return null;`. Try to understand what the answers do, not copy-paste them blindly

Answer (score 0):

Check if tts array has null elements before you try to create your adapter in onPostExecute method. My guess is the exception gets triggered in the third line of this method: ArrayAdapter adapter=....
You can also put try/catch(Exception ex) around it to see if and what exception it catches.

**Edit:**
I think I spotted the problem - your **doInBackground** method should return your List ( or Array), instead of null. The returned value is then used as input paremeter by **onPostExecute** This is from offical documentation

> doInBackground(Params...) ...The result of the computation must be returned by this step and will be passed back to the last step...

Comment: I tried surrounding it with _try-catch(Exception exc)_but nothing new happens.

Comment: A try catch around the adapter constructor won't solve the problem. That's not when the `getView` is called